# Panel regression with proportion as both dependent and independent

Tags: regression, panel-data, proportion

I need to do a panel regression where my data is proportions for both dependent and one of the independent variables.

I do not have the underlying data for the proportion so I cannot expand the data and use logistic regression.

Any ideas on how to handle this? Poisson regression maybe?

Comment: Without the binary data for the two proportions how could any form of regression be possible?

Comment: I dont know anything about panel data, but for cross sectional data, an often used technique for modeling a proportion as the dv is beta regression. Here is a starting point I can suggest: cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I'm guessing that it would be something like proportion of the vote for a Democratic presidential candidate regressed on the proportion of the population that is black across states and time.

In any case, Poisson is certainly not the right answer. It's not obvious to me why there's a problem in general with this form of regression. I think that there can be some false causal relationships if the two proportions have the same denominator, but I don't have a reference for that handy.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood.  I thought there were binary observations that led to single proportions.  If you have a set of proportions for the outcomes and the predictor than you can use regression methods.  I agree with Charlie Poisson regression is for count data.  But ordinary linear regression is possible and you culd use the logit transformation on the dependent variable if you want to transform the range of the DV from [0,1] to the entire line.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, good point about trying to get the range to make sense by using logit. But panel methods for logit are a bit tricky (if we allow for intra-unit correlations across periods, which is important for inference in panel data).

Comment: @MichaelChernick Is it possible to do logit transformation without having the underlying numerator/denominator? My case is similar to what Charlie explains.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with panle data. Maybe Charlie is better equipped to answer you.  But my colleague Joe Hilbe has a lot of experience with panel data and has written books on the topic of generalized linear models, method like GEE for longitudinal data and the use of negative binomial regression and Poisson regression. Maybe his negative binomial regression book would be healthy